# AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'all_with_related_persons_and_score'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

`File "/home/syed007/PYTHON/myprojects/MyMDB/django/core/views.py", line 60, in MovieDetail
    queryset = Movie.objects.all_with_related_persons_and_score()
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'all_with_related_persons_and_score'`

I'm using Django 2.2.4 on Python 3.6

when run "python3 manage.py makemigrations core", got the above error then changed the views script and that worked. But we cannot make views. However that created my models. But again, when running the command,"python3 manage.py runserver", got this error --

```
class MovieDetail(DetailView):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all_with_related_persons_and_score()



from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.aggregates import Sum


class MovieManager(models.Manager):

    def all_with_related_persons(self):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        qs = qs.select_related('director')
        qs = qs.prefetch_related('writers', 'actors')
        return qs

    def all_with_related_persons_and_score(self):
        qs = self.all_with_related_persons()
        qs = qs.annotate(score=Sum('vote__value'))
        return qs

`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign that Manager class to an model like this:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    # fields
    objects = MovieManager()
```

More information can be found in [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers).

Comment: Wow! How come I miss that. This will surely resolve the problem.

Comment: I used it for all the other models, I do not know, how I missed it. New to Linux, not to Python. Anyway thanks.